# What do these asterisks mean in Azure DevOps 'Test Plans' menu (see screenshot)

Tags: azure-devops

Was just wondering what these asterisks meant in the left side 'Test Plans' menu in Azure DevOps (highlighted in yellow)?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This asterisk for Test Plans highlights that you are using "New Test Plans Page" preview feature. You can switch this option off and see the asterisk is disappeared.

You can manipulate preview features under [Preview Features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/navigation/preview-features?view=azure-devops#enable-features-for-your-use) menu at your account:
[image]

or like this if you using "New account manager" preview feature

[image]